# Is there anything like Sublime SFTP for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, ftp-client

[Sublime FTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)

I think emacs would be great with something like this added so you don't have to use an external FTP client.

I know there is TRAMP, but the folder mapping and diff local vs remote features seem like a nice thing to have.  Or am I just not identifying a way to handle this some other way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "folder mapping" and "diff local vs remote".

Comment: SublimeFTP kinda sounds like the answers here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/512/dired-as-an-ftp-client

Comment: I think this is spot on! I didn't know you could just "copy" between dired windows.